# python re regex matching in string with multiple () parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have this string

```
cmd = "show run IP(k1) new Y(y1) add IP(dev.maintserial):Y(dev.maintkeys)"
```

What is a regex to first match exactly `"IP(dev.maintserial):Y(dev.maintkeys)"`

There might be a different path inside the parenthesis, like (name.dev.serial), so it is not like there will always be one dot there.

I though of something like this:
`re.search('(IP\(.*?\):Y\(.*?\))', cmd)` but this will also match the single IP(k1) and Y(y1

My usage will be:

```
If "IP(*):Y(*)" in cmd:
 do substitution of IP(dev.maintserial):Y(dev.maintkeys) to Y(dev.maintkeys.IP(dev.maintserial))
```

How can I then do the above substitution? In the if condition I want to do this change in order: `from IP(path_to_IP_key):Y(path_to_Y_key) to Y(path_to_Y_key.IP(path_to_IP_key))` , so IP is inside Y at the end after the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
r"IP\(([^)]*\..+)\):Y\(([^)]*\..+)\)"
```

You can [try it](https://regex101.com/r/ODYHBC/1) with your string. It matches the entire string `IP(dev.maintserial):Y(dev.maintkeys)` with groups `dev.maintserial` and `dev.maintkeys`.

The RE matches `IP(`, zero or more characters that are not a closing parenthesis (`[^)]*`), a period `.` (`\.`), one or more of any characters (`.+`), then `):Y(`, ... (between the parentheses -- same as above), `)`.

**Example Usage**

```
import re

cmd = "show run IP(k1) new Y(y1) add IP(dev.maintserial):Y(dev.maintkeys)"

# compile regular expression
p = re.compile(r"IP\(([^)]*\..+)\):Y\(([^)]*\..+)\)")

s = p.search(cmd)
# if there is a match, s is not None
if s:
    print(f"{s[0]}\n{s[1]}\n{s[2]}")
    a = "Y(" + s[2] + ".IP(" + s[1] + "))"
    print(f"\n{a}")
```

Above `p.search(cmd)` "[s]can[s] through [`cmd`] looking for the first location where this regular expression [`p`] produces a match, and return[s] a corresponding match object" ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search)). `None` is the return value if there is no match. If there is a match, `s[0]` gives the entire match, `s[1]` gives the first parenthesized subgroup, and `s[2]` gives the second parenthesized subgroup ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.__getitem__)).

**Output**

```
IP(dev.maintserial):Y(dev.maintkeys)
dev.maintserial
dev.maintkeys

Y(dev.maintkeys.IP(dev.maintserial))
```

Comment: What about the substitution in the if clause?

Comment: @JON What is `*` in your `if` condition?

Comment: Just to show that there might be a different path inside the parenthesis, like (name.dev.serial), so it is not like there will always be one dot separating 2 words there.

Comment: @JON I have edited my answer. Please let me know if that is what you wanted or not!

Comment: in the if condition I want to do this change in order or substitution: from IP(path_to_IP_key):Y(path_to_Y_key) to Y(path_to_Y_key.IP(path_to_IP_key)) , so IP is inside Y at the end after the dot.

Comment: @JON I thought your question said you wanted substitution of `IP(dev.maintserial):Y(dev.maintkeys)` to `Y(dev.maintkeys.IP(dev.maintserial))`. My answer above does this. Do you need to use `re.sub()` or is the approach I used above okay? You can apply the same method I used above to your new string.

Comment: What is the equivalent regex that matches : Y(key1.key2.IP(key1.key2.key3) , with the same logic as above?

Answer (score 2):

This should work as it is more restrictive.
`(IP\([^\)]+\):Y\(.*?\))`

`[^\)]+` means at least one character that isn't a closing parenthesis.

`.*?` in yours is too open ended allowing almost anything to be in until "`):Y(`"

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 negated character classes `[^()]*` to match any character except parenthesis, and omit the outer capture group for a match only.

To prevent a partial word match, you might start matching `IP` with a word boundary `\b`

```
\bIP\([^()]*\):Y\([^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xiWC3J/1)